# Pass data from vueJs component to Laravel blade

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

I have a button (anchor tag) in a VueJs component, when clicked, it routes to another page, loading a laravel blade view. 
Inside vueJs component

```
<a href="/checkout">Checkout</a>
```

This route returns a laravel blade file.

```
    Route::get('/checkout', function(){ 
        return view('checkout');
    });
```

Now I have a data property in my vueJs component which I would need to use in checkout blade view. How do I pass this data from vueJs component to Laravel blade view. 
NB: I'm familiar with passing data from laravel to VueJs but not the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

first of all the way you are trying, anchor tag is not a good way. and I donw know How Many data you need to send so I can suggest simple and easy way which is params.
suppose you need to send data id, name, address.

```
  <a :href="'/checkout?id='+id+'&name='+name+'&address='+address">Checkout</a>
```

and in laravel

```
Route::get('/checkout', function(Request $request){ 
    $data=$request->all()
    return view('checkout')with('data',$data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Zubaer. What better way can I do this since anchor tag is not a good way? Passing the data as URL params isn't what I'd prefer since it will expose the data and could be manipulated.

Comment: you can send data in form data in a post method and after that redirect to the route with these data.

Comment: I tried this, but the redirect in the controller method didnt work. I did an axios post request from vueJs and received it in my controller method, doing a redirect with the data is the issue now.

Comment: i have to see how you did than I can know where can be the mistake, but the one I gave you here , it will work